# How to use ADSL modem as bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I receive internet through a Hauwei HG531s (ADSL2+ modem + WiFi router). Because I want to use things like advanced QoS and do some port forwarding, I got a Asus AC-66U router. I want the Huawei router to be transparent; in other words, I want it to act just like an ethernet cable connected to the WAN port of the ASUS router, so that I wouldn't have to worry about having 2 NATs or 2 port forwarding to worry about.

The Huawei router connects to the internet via PPPoE. I already know the username and password. 
[image]

Because I wanted to use Asus router as main (and only) router, I changed the connection type from PPPoE to Bridge and enabled LAN1 since that's where the ASUS router is connected.
[image]
In the Asus router's web interface, I selected PPPoE and used the username and password that I had been using on the Huawei router to gain access to the internet. However, I was not able to connect. I got "Authentication failed! Please check PPPoE Username and PPPoE Password". So, I thought maybe my account is tied to the mac address of the Huawei router. Luckily, I can change the mac address of the Asus router, which I changed to that of the Huawei router. This time, I got "No response from your Internet Service Provider(ISP), please consult your ISP."

What might I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Your Huawei modem may be using some encapsulation (such as Mac Encapsulated Routing (or MER)) for your connection that your ASUS modem/router isn't providing so the connection isn't being permitted. UK ISP Sky do this. You may be best just putting your ASUS router into the DMZ of your Huawei (if it's capable of doing this) and then you'll not need to worry about port forwarding as everything will be forwarded to the ASUS.

Comment: You can see on the first picture that the LLC encapsulation is used. Also, the Asus router is not a modem.